# Múltiplos usuários e autenticação - Django

Tags: python, django

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em Django que possui dois tipos de usuários: Cliente e Contador. Cada um se autêntica e possui chaves que lhes identificam  diferentes. O Cliente tem como chave primária o seu CNPJ. Já o contador tem como chave a composição do seu CRC, CNPJ e chave primária do Cliente (CNPJ). Ou seja, podemos ter vários contadores com o mesmo CNPJ e CRC mas CNPJ (do Cliente) diferente. A imagem a seguir mostra o modelo Entidade-Relacional desse "mini-mundo".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu problema é: Como implementar isso em Django, já que ele permite somente um usuário no seu UserModel?

A minha abordagem frustada é a seguinte:

1. Crio um UserProfile que herda de AbstractBaseUser e PermissionsMixin (configuro o settings.py para esse novo user).
2. Coloco todos os parâmetros que são comuns entre Cliente e Contador no UserProfile.
3. Crio dois modelos: Cliente e Contador, que herdam de UserProfile.
4. No contador faço o relacionamento ForeignKey(Cliente) e coloco os atributos que somente pertencem ao Contador - nome e crc.

A minha dúvida é: Dado esse modelo, qual a melhor forma de implementar esses dois tipos de usuários que se autenticam e tem chaves primárias diferentes?

Arquivo *Models.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, UserManager)

class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    username = models.CharField(
        'CNPJ', max_length=20, unique=True
    )

    razao_social = models.CharField(
                'Razão Social', max_length=100)

    telefone = models.CharField('Telefone',max_length=20, blank=True)
    celular = models.CharField('celular',max_length=20, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField('E-mail', unique = True, max_length=255,)

    is_active = models.BooleanField('Esta ativo?', blank=True, default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField('E da equipe?', blank=True, default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField('Data de entrada', auto_now_add=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username' #Campo que e unico e referencia da hora do login
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email'] #Para criar super-usuario

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    def get_full_name(self):
        return str(self)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Usuario"
        verbose_name_plural = "Usuarios"

#Done
class Cliente(UserProfile):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Cliente"
        verbose_name_plural = "Clientes"

#Done
class Contador(UserProfile):

    clientes = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank = True,null=True)

    crc =  models.CharField('CRC',unique=True,  max_length=20)
    nome = models.CharField('Nome', blank= True, max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.crc

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.nome

    def get_full_name(self):
        return str(self)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("crc", "email"),)
        verbose_name = "Contador"
        verbose_name_plural = "Contadores"
```

Também coloquei no site [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/106F7a29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A autenticação deles deve ser através do e-mail, sendo este um atributo único. Assim você mantém as chaves primárias de cada tipo de usuário.

Você pode criar uma classe Perfil(Cliente ou Contador) e depois outra chamada UserPerfil, nessa você define qual perfil cada usuário vai ter no seu sistema. E quando for acessar áreas aonde só o cliente ou contador tem acesso você faz a verificação `userPerfil.objects.filter(perfil='Cliente')`

```
class Perfil(models.CharField):
   nome = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   profile = models.ForeignKey(Perfil, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

As informações sobre Cliente e Contador vc cria dois models.
Lembre-se que a primary-key do django é o id, criado automático. A chave primária que você esta querendo no contador vai sempre se repetir quebrando as regras de normalização. Você apenas relacionando cliente dentro de contador pode recuperar as informações mais fáceis como quais contadores cliente x tem, quais o clientes o contador y tem e por ai vai

```
class Cliente(models.CharField):
    cnpj = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Contator(models.CharField):
    crc = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: A autenticação tem que ser diferente para os dois modelos. Cliente por cnpj e contador por crc.

Comment: Qual a relação do model cliente e contador com UserProfile? Está faltando essa "ligação", certo?

Comment: A relação é que você vai associar cada usuário a um perfil(Cliente ou contador) nessa classe é ela que faz a ligação pois ela recebe um usuário e um perfil

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html Acho que isso resolve todo o seu problema de trabalhar com tipos de usuário

Comment: Não estou imaginando como funciona trabalhar com "flags". Como crio um form que seja autenticável partindo de um modelo que herda de models.Model? (é o exemplo da classe Student do link que você me enviou)